# check how many times string contains character 'g' in eligible string

Tags: java

How we can check any string that contains any character how may time....
example:
**engineering**  is a string contains how many times **'g'** in complete string

Comment: Convert it to character array and loop through it checking for matches. Check out [java.util.String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Answer (score 56):

I know this is and old question, but there is an option that wasn't answered and it's pretty simple one-liner:

```
int count = string.length() - string.replaceAll("g","").length()
```

Comment: I think you should add beginIndex and endIndex to the substring

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely a lot easier than having to download the apache commons lang API.

Answer (score 38):

Try this

```
int count = StringUtils.countMatches("engineering", "e");
```

More about [StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) can be learned from the question: [How do I use StringUtils in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660151/how-do-i-use-stringutils-in-java)

Comment: Where do you get that `StringUtils` from?

Comment: Please check this commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html

Answer (score 8):

I would use a `Pattern` and `Matcher`:

```
String string = "engineering";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([gG])"); //case insensitive, use [g] for only lower
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
int count = 0;
while (matcher.find()) count++;
```

Answer (score 7):

Although Regex will work fine, but it is not really required here. You can do it simply using a `for-loop` to maintain a `count` for a character.

You would need to convert your string to a char array: -

```
    String str = "engineering";
    char toCheck = 'g';
    int count = 0;

    for (char ch: str.toCharArray()) { 
        if (ch == toCheck) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
```

or, you can also do it **without converting** to `charArray`: -

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    if (str.charAt(i) == toCheck) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check there is count mismatch.

Comment: @sunleo.. For which code? Well, both of them are working fine. Just checked it.

Comment: @sunleo.. Please try them. They both are giving `3` as count in my case.

Comment: both are working fine thank you.Sorry for inconvenience.Eclipse not refreshed the latest class.

Comment: @sunleo.. Haha! No worries. Happens sometimes :)

Answer (score 5):

use org.apache.commons.lang3 package for use StringUtils class.
download jar file and place it into lib folder of your web application.

```
int count = StringUtils.countMatches("engineering", "e");
```

Answer (score 4):

```
String s = "engineering";
char c = 'g';
s.replaceAll("[^"+ c +"]", "").length();
```

Comment: As a note, if `char c` comes from user input, this approach is vulnerable to regex injection. (similar to SQL injection)

Answer (score 3):

Use regex `[g]` to find the char and count the findings as below:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[g]");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("engineering");
    int countCharacter = 0;
    while(matcher.find()) {
        countCharacter++;
    }
    System.out.println(countCharacter);
```

If you want case insensitive count, use regex as `[gG]` in the Pattern.

Answer (score 1):

this is a very very old question but this might help someone ("_")

you can Just simply use this code

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String mainString = "This is and that is he is and she is";
    //To find The "is" from the mainString
    String whatToFind = "is";
    int result = countMatches(mainString, whatToFind);
    System.out.println(result);
}

public static int countMatches(String mainString, String whatToFind){
    String tempString = mainString.replaceAll(whatToFind, "");
    //this even work for on letter
    int times = (mainString.length()-tempString.length())/whatToFind.length();
    
    //times should be 4
    return times;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try Java-8 way. Easy, simple and more readable.

```
long countOfA = str.chars().filter(ch -> ch == 'g').count();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following :

```
String str = "engineering";
int letterCount = 0;
int index = -1;
while((index = str.indexOf('g', index+1)) > 0)
    letterCount++;
System.out.println("Letter Count = " + letterCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through it and keep a count of the letter you want.

```
public class Program {
    public static int countAChars(String s) {
        int count = 0;
        for(char c : s.toCharArray()) {
            if('a' == c) {
               count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

or you can use StringUtils to get a count.

```
int count = StringUtils.countMatches("engineering", "e");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question and it is in Java but I will answer it in Python.  This might be helpful:

```
string = 'E75;Z;00001;'

a = string.split(';')

print(len(a)-1)
```