# something like equalsIgnoreCase while using indexOf

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am using this code, to get the index of a String in an Array.

```
int n = Arrays.asList(Names).indexOf(textBox.getText());
```

The problem here is, if the String in **textBox** is different in **case** to its similar String in the Array. It returns **-1**. How can make it something like **equalsIgnoreCase** in case of String comparision.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different approach where internally make sure ignore case.

```
public static int indexOfIgnoreCase(String[] strs, String text){

   int n = strs.length;
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
       if(strs[i].equalsIgnoreCase(text))
         return i;
   }
   return -1;
}
int n = indexOfIgnoreCase(Names,textBox.getText());
```

Comment: Though i change the String in textBox to upper/lower case, i don't know how it is in the given array.

Comment: Moreover the Strings in the Array are being used as AutoCompletes. So i cannot convert them to upper/lower case(wont look good in dropdown). May be must create a new array with all Strings as lower/upper case. But its not the best approach

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Collator class. in Here you can set different levels for your comparison.
you can ignore lower and upper cases, and set some specific language charackters. In German for example it can set ß equal to ss.

here´s some documentary: 
[Collator class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html)

Edit : here´s an example Code for you

```
private int indexOf(String[] original, String search) {
    Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(); 
    collator.setStrength(Collator.SECONDARY);
    for(int i = 0;i<original.length;++i) {
        if(collator.equals(search, original[i]))
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Watch the example, this is what you are looking for i hope

Comment: So now i really figured out what you want :D you just have to give the original String, and the String you are looking for in your original to this method, and it reutrn you the index of the search String, or -1

Comment: But this is to get the index of a substring in a given parent string. My need is to get the index of a String from an Array of Strings. without changing the order of Strings in the Array .

Answer (score 3):

You can use [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#indexOfIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29) class of Apache commons libraries or [this](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#indexOfIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) If you don't want to download the library look at the [source code](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/alibaba/citrus/tool/antx-autoconfig/1.0.10/antx-autoconfig-1.0.10-sources.jar!/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.java?format=ok) for logic to create the method. The [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660151/how-do-i-use-stringutils-in-java) link for using StringUtils

If you want to find the index of String from array of strings then there is another library [ArrayUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html) which has a method [indexOf](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html)

here's the implementation of indexOf

```
 public static int indexOf(Object[] array, Object objectToFind, int startIndex) {
        if (array == null) {
            return INDEX_NOT_FOUND;
        }
        if (startIndex < 0) {
            startIndex = 0;
        }
        if (objectToFind == null) {
            for (int i = startIndex; i < array.length; i++) {
                if (array[i] == null) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = startIndex; i < array.length; i++) {
                if (objectToFind.equals(array[i])) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
        }
        return INDEX_NOT_FOUND;
    }
```

since you can see that it uses .equals() I suggest you to

1) create a custom string class

2) add it to the array

3) override the .equals method like this

```
class StringCustom
{
String string;
//implement getters and setters
public String equals(Object o)
{
return this.getString().equalsIgnoreCase(((String)o).getString());
}
}
```

Comment: But this is to get the index of a substring in a given parent string

Comment: @Archie.bpgc what else do you want?

Comment: My need is to get the index of a String from an Array of Strings. without changing the order of Strings in the Array

Comment: @Archie.bpgc : you can use arrayutils class also. but this won't help you with the Ignore case stuff. still searching...

Comment: @Archie.bpgc : one solution would be to create a custom String class and override the equals method of it. then use indexOf() of ArrayUtils since the source code uses equals method

Answer (score 0):

You can extend `ArrayList` in this way

```
    public class StringArrayList extends ArrayList<String> {
        @Override
        public boolean contains(Object o) {
            String paramStr = (String)o;
            for (String s : this) {
                if (paramStr.equalsIgnoreCase(s)) return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public int indexOf(Object o) {
            String paramStr = (String)o;
            int index = 0;
            for (String s : this) {
                if (paramStr.equalsIgnoreCase(s)) return index;
                index++;
            }
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

Eventually :

```
int n = new StringArrayList(Arrays.asList(Names)).indexOf(textBox.getText());
```