# Case Insensitive String Array Comparison

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, string, case-sensitive

I am coding in Java and I understand well that I can compare most arrays with `Arrays.equals`, and I can compare strings case insensitively with `String.equalsIgnoreCase`, but is there a way to specifically compare Arrays of strings case insensitively?

sample code:

```
class Foo {
    String[] array; // don't care about case

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Foo obj) {
        // bunch of stuff to check equality
        if (!Arrays.equals(array, obj.array)) return false; // case insensitive?
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll have to do it yourself, using a loop. Should be faster than asking the question.

Comment: u can use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15269723/array-contains-without-case-sensitive-lookup

Comment: Based on what you said you know... loop over the arrays simultaneously and use `String.equalsIgnoreCase` on each element

Comment: May be helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817413/something-like-equalsignorecase-while-using-indexof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code wont compile as you are not overriding the Object's equals method which has signature like `public boolean equals(Object obj)`

Also to do comparison, you could do the following in your modified equals as below:

```
if (array == foo.array) {
    return true;
}

if (array == null || foo.array == null) {
    return false;
}

int length = array.length;

if (foo.length != length)
        return false;

    for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
        String string1 = array[i];
        String string2 = foo.array[i];
        if (!(string1==null ? string2==null : string1.equalsIgnoreCase(string2)))
            return false;
    }
return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

For things like that I keep a Utility class where i define a static comparator method (as String[] case insensitive comparison is not a Type specific logic and can be reused somewhere else in the program).

```
public static boolean caseInsensitiveCompare(String[] array1, String[] array2) {
    // validate arguments
    condition(allNotNullOrEmpty(array1) && allNotNullOrEmpty(array2));

    if (array1 == array2) return true;
    if (array1.length != array2.length) return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        if (!array1[i].equalsIgnoreCase(array2[i])) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

P.S. instead of writing this

```
if (!Arrays.equals(array, obj.array)) return false; // case insensitive?
    return true;
```

write this

```
return !Arrays.equals(array, obj.array);
```

or use Intellij :)