# getposition() of adapter is not being called in Android

Tags: android

I have a spinner whose elements are save in sharedPrefrences. When I choose any element from the spinner and clicks on save button it saves that element in sharedPref and whenever I come back to this activity the spinner is selected with the same element that I'd choosen and saved. The problem arises when I close my app and removes from currently running apps in my phone. In this case when I open my app and goes to that activity, spinner is selected with the 0th element. I'm getting the saved element from sharedPref but getPosition() is not being called. Why is it happening?

Here's my method:

```
public boolean setBranchIds(ArrayList<String> tdBrlist) {
    try {
        branchList = tdBrlist;
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                branchSpinner = new Spinner(Activity_Settings.this);


                TableRow.LayoutParams tdpid_spinner_params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                        0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 3f);
                branchSpinner.setLayoutParams(tdpid_spinner_params);
                branchRow.addView(branchSpinner);
                branchSpinner.setPrompt("Select Branch");

                if (branchList.size() > 0) {
                    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            Activity_Settings.this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                            branchList);
                    branchSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

                    String branch = mActivity.getSharedPreferences(
                            Utility.PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                            .getString(Utility.BRANCH, "");
                    System.out.println("====branch===: "+branch);
                    if (!branch.equals("")) {
                        branchIndex = getIndex(branch);   
                        System.out.println("=====positionbranch:    
         "+branchIndex);
                        branchSpinner.setSelection(branchIndex);
                    }
                }
            }

        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
private int getIndex(String branch) {
    for (int i = 0; i < branchList.size(); i++) {
        if (branchList.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(branch)) {
            System.out.println("======i: "+i);
            return i;

        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

LogCat values:

```
12-17 13:50:51.502: I/System.out(13229): ====branch===: B1
12-17 13:50:51.502: I/System.out(13229): ====branchlist===: [Select, B1, B2,   
B3,B4]
12-17 13:50:51.502: I/System.out(13229): ======i: 1
12-17 13:50:51.502: I/System.out(13229): =====positionbranch: 1
```

LogCat values when I return back:

```
12-17 13:53:10.932: I/System.out(14895): ====branch===: B1
12-17 13:53:10.932: I/System.out(14895): ====branchlist===: [Select, B1, B2
, B3, B4]
12-17 13:53:10.932: I/System.out(14895): =====positionbranch: -1
```

Comment: Post your log. did you get `branch` value?

Comment: ye I'm getting branch value

Comment: I think you should call `indexOf()` in the `ArrayList` instead of `getPosition()` in the `Adapter`

Comment: @RivuChakraborty I tried that too. But it didn't work either

Comment: You can get that position from branchList

Comment: @SheenaTyagi then please post your adapter

Comment: @SheenaTyagi have you checked my answer?

Comment: on using indexOf(), I'm getting branch value and there are all the elements in branchList, still its not getting index from this arraylist

Comment: `if (branch != "") {` this not how we compare strings in java

Comment: @SheenaTyagi: Sheena see this post [something like equalsIgnoreCase while using indexOf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817413/something-like-equalsignorecase-while-using-indexof) and also use `String.equals` instead of `!=`

Comment: Edited code. still not working :(

Comment: post your logcat then

Comment: @pskink code edited..

Comment: so inside `getIndex` log each loop iteration with `branchList.get(i)` and `branch`

Answer (score 3):

May you have to Replace:

```
int branchIndex = pinnerAdapter.getPosition(branch);
branchSpinner.setSelection(branchIndex);
```

With this:

```
branchSpinner.setSelection(list.indexOf(branch));
```

Comment: Its not working when I cleared my app from currently running apps in background :/

Comment: Removed your app? Means?