# StringUtils not working even with included imports

Tags: java, spaces, apache-commons-lang3

I trying the [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958955/how-to-remove-duplicate-white-spaces-in-string-using-java) into my application to remove multiple unnecessary spaces:

```
while (cleantext.indexOf("  ") != -1)
     cleantext = StringUtils.replace(cleantext, "  ", " ");
```

But got this message error:

```
Main.java:101: error: cannot find symbol
    line = StringUtils.replace
```

I did following imports and neither worked so far -- [lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660151/how-do-i-use-stringutils-in-java) and [StringUtils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660151/how-do-i-use-stringutils-in-java):

```
import java.lang.*;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
```

Either way the problem does not go away. So how to get this fixed?

Edited:

Thanks for the suggestions. I am running on command line on Linux terminal.

I was using the command:

```
$ javac -cp "./" Main.java
```

Then changing the command to:

```
$ javac -cp jar1  Main.java
```

Gave me the error:

```
Main.java:8: error: package org.apache.commons.lang3 does not exist
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
```

Final edit:

I replaced the "while" content in the code for the following command line as example previously given on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958955/how-to-remove-duplicate-white-spaces-in-string-using-java):

```
str=str.trim().replaceAll("(\\s)+", "$1");
```

That did the trick. Problem solved! Thanks a ton for all the suggestions.

Comment: Do you actually have the library in your classpath at compile time?

Comment: Show us your complete code along with the `javac` output from whatever IDE (if any) you are using.

Comment: We need to know a bit more about your configuration to help, e.g are you doing builds from the command line or using an IDE, Maven, etc.

Comment: why are you not changing the command as : `javac -cp /path/to/commons-lang3-3.1.jar Main.java` ?

Comment: jar1 is the jar path of `commons-lang3-x.x.jar`?

Comment: The error seems to indicate that the binary jar containing the org.apache.commons.lang3  package is missing from your path.