# how to reverse the word using list iterator in java

Tags: java, string

```
class StringRev{
    public static void main(String args[]){
    String str = "He is the one";
    String temp = "";
    String finalString = "";
        for(int i =str.length()-1;i>=0;i--){
            temp +=i!=0?str.charAt(i):str.charAt(i)+" ";
            if(str.charAt(i) == ' '||i==0){
                for(int j=temp.length()-1;j>=0;j--){
                    finalString += temp.charAt(j);
                }
                temp = "";
            }
        }
            System.out.println(finalString);
    }
}
```

I tried to solve.I have to reverse the string `"He is the one"` to `"one the is He"`.
I have written some programs in Java but am looking for other best solutions.
 Suggest any possible ways to minimize the current.

Comment: Simply just split string using space, will give you an array of words, iterate reversely and append it to new string.

Answer (score 0):

Simply just `split` given string on spaces, will give you an array of words, iterate reversely and append it to new string as following:

```
String string = "He is the one";
System.out.println("Original String: " + string);

String[] arr = string.split(" ");

String reverseString = "";
for(int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    reverseString += arr[i] + " ";
}

System.out.println("Reverse String: " + reverseString);
```

OR you can use `Arrays` utility to convert split-ed string into `List`, make it reverse it using `Collection` utility `reverse` method, iterate over it and create string as following:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(string.split(" "));
Collections.reverse(list);

String reserveStringUsingList = "";
for(String str : list){
    reserveStringUsingList += str + " ";
}

System.out.println("Reverse String using List: " + reserveStringUsingList);
```

Comment: And now you even try to steal things from my answer and present as your own? Pathetic.

Comment: We all have been steeling from JAVA. I just improved my answer. While, there was no need to add detail about trim().

Comment: Yeah, you improved it after reading my answer. Nobody is stealing from Java, looks like you don't understand the meaning of that word. I usually don't mind when people do this, but If you steal and at the same time try to make my answer look like crap, then I'm not going to just silently let it slip, because this attitude is really not welcome on SO.

Comment: Ok, I have updated my answer. Don't get arrogant, perhaps you better understand the game of words.

Answer (score 0):

Split the String into words and the iterate downwards and append the words back to a String.

```
public class StringRev{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String input = "He is the one";
        String output = "";
        String[] inputSplit = input.split(" ");

        for(int i=inputSplit.length-1; i>=0; i--){
            output += inputSplit[i] + " ";
        }

        System.out.println(output.trim()); //remove trailing space
    }
}
```

If you can use `Collections` and `StringUtil` then it's even more straight forward.

```
public class StringRev{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String input = "He is the one";
        String[] inputSplit = input.split(" ");

        Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(inputSplit));
        String output = StringUtil.join(Arrays.asList(inputSplit), " ");

        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

Comment: To use StringUtil or StringUtils class, we need to use additional library. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660151/how-do-i-use-stringutils-in-java#answer-8660166

Comment: @ParkashKumar that's kind of obvious isn't it? When you want to use Collections you need `java.util.Collections` and I'm not having a go about it in your answer.. Stop trying to make other people's answers look less good than yours by all means just to get those few points..

Comment: That's not all about the points. Its regarding simple and straightforward answer, which satisfies OP's requirement. While, to use java.util.Collections you will not require any additional library except the JDK / JRE, obviously you will be using for your java program to run.

Comment: "If you can use `Collections` and `StringUtil`"

Comment: I really didn't mean to lower your answer. Sorry, if you minded my initial comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution you asked for, using [`ListIterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html):

**Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String str = "He is the one";
    System.out.println(str);
    System.out.println(reverseWords(str));
}

static String reverseWords(String str) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(str.length());
    List<String> words = Arrays.asList(str.split(" "));
    if(!words.isEmpty()) {
        ListIterator<String> it = words.listIterator(words.size());
        result.append(it.previous());
        while (it.hasPrevious()) {
            result.append(' ').append(it.previous());
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

**Output:**

```
He is the one
one the is He
```