# StringUtils.isNumeric is undefined method

Tags: java, import, compiler-errors, apache-stringutils

I have imported that library:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.StringUtils;
```

And tried to use some of methods, but failed:

```
StringUtils.isNumeric("2398sdf");
```

IDE keep saying me that, method is undefined. What is wrong here?

Comment: Well what makes you think it *should* be present? I can't see it in the documentation: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/StringUtils.html

Comment: Did you download the jar with StringUtils ? .. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660151/how-do-i-use-stringutils-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong `StringUtils` class. You're importing [`org.apache.commons.codec.binary.StringUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/StringUtils.html), but it looks like you want [`org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) or [`org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html). The first of these *doesn't* have an `isNumeric` method, whereas both of the `lang`-based ones do.

Obviously this means you'll need the ["commons lang"](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) library to be in your classpath. (Which class you import will depend on which version you use.)

Comment: Heck, you can have this answer :(

Comment: Eclipse confused me, thank you for the answer @JonSkeet)

Answer (score 3):

The `StringUtils.isNumeric` method is defined in the package `org.apache.commons.lang3` and not in the one you specified.